# Modifying specific strings for different languages using different common modules (Android)

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, multilingual

here's something very weird and I clearly not understand what's happening but maybe one of you can turn the light on inside my brain ...

I have a project on AndroidStudio with multiple common files (and multiple languages) which are used in different apps :

```
|Common core
|-   default module 1
|-   default module 2
|-   default images
|- | default strings
   |-   danish (default) in "values" folder
   |-   english in "values-en" folder
   |-   swedish in "values-sv" folder
|App one
|-   specific module 3
|-   specific module 4
|-   specific images
|- | specific strings
   |-   in "values" folder
|App two
...
```

---

FYI, In my apps, I have a *AppApplication.java* file which is the first file called in the app and which is used to set up my application, like the menu configuration, some specifics variables and the languages settings.

Now, when I'm compiling App 1 (for ex.) which uses a default module from the common core and I want to change any of the strings or images from the default module, I just put them into the specific images/strings app folder with the same names they have in the common default images/strings folders and they will be overridden.

That's perfectly working. And I'm happy with that. But ... the real problem is...

When I want to set up languages configuration :

---

## Situation #1

*_"I want to use the default language (danish) in my App 1"_*

My *AppApplication.java* file isn't calling any specific language configuration and everything is fine. *(Inside the common core files, I set up the local "DK" as default.)* My app has the danish language with all strings from the default strings of the "values" folder.

If I want to change some specific strings in my app, I put them into my app specific strings "values" folder and they override the default strings.
!! Perfect !!

---

## Situation #2

*_"I want to use the swedish language in my App 1"_*

My *AppApplication.java* file has the following lines :

```
LocaleAnswer[] localeAnswers = new LocaleAnswer[]{new LocaleAnswer(new Locale("sv", "SE"), "Swedish")};
    public LocaleAnswer[] getLocaleChoices(){
        return localeAnswers;
    }
```

(*I can, without any problem, add multiple languages inside my LocaleAnswers array. The common core will then take care of it by showing a dialog asking which language you want to use on startup*)

If my app doesn't need to modify any of the default strings, then, I don't have any specific strings file to worry about and we are OK. The app compiles well and the app is in swedish. YOUHOU !! Perfect !!

BUT, if I need to change a string, what I thought was to put this specific string inside my app "values" folder. But no :( :( :( :(
The string isn't overridden.

I think I know why : the project compiles everything, then when I run my app, the last call regarding languages is in my *AppApplication.java* file and it says to use the swedish file. So, it uses the swedish file, as asked, from the default "values-sv" folder. OK.

Let's try to bypass this by renaming my "values" folder inside my app to "values-sv", so that when the app will call the swedish strings file, it will uses my specific app strings and uses the default ones for those I haven't modified. HAHAHAHAH you know what ??? I just create an "auto-reboot phone" app :D . App compiles but when it tries to install, phone is rebooting, and rebooting, and rebooting and rebooting again and again. I had to start the phone in *SafeMode* (volume down + menu) during one of the reboot to have the possibility to erase my installed app and then rebooting the phone normally. Huuu :/ That doesn't help very much.

Let's try to bypass that by duplicating my "values-sv" folder inside my app and renaming one of them to "values". So, now I have a "values" and a "values-sv" folder in my app and both are containing the same strings file (with the specific swedish strings I want to change from default ones). And TADAAAAMMM !! It's working !!

Coooooool, BUT, HOW ? WHY ?

---

## Questions

1. I don't want this duplicate strings file on two different folders in order to have my strings modified ! How can I have my default strings being modified by specific ones when I choose a specific language other than the default one with only one strings file in my app ?
2. This one is not a very important question for the project but, it could be very interesting to know why when you add only a string folder with a specific language name like "values-sv" in my app it makes the entire phone reboot ? I would say that the app is looking for default values that means a "values" folder and as there is none, BOUM, error ! But why the app doesn't just crash ? Why the entire phone is rebooting ?

Thanks in advance ;)
C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answers

1. In fact, in my strings files, I specify a "content_provider_authority" and an "auth_account_type" for a content provider.

   If you duplicate those two strings sets in an other "values-xx" folder than the default "values" one, the phone crashes and reboot indefinitely.

   So, I now have a "values" folder with a *strings.xml* file which contains only "content_provider_authority" and "auth_account_type". In my "values-sv" folder I have another *strings.xml* file which contains all the specific strings I want to modify from the defaults "values-sv" folder if there are some. :D

   It works well and I can define default language, one specific language or multiple languages choice without any trouble !!
2. Why the phone is rebooting with a content provider conflict ? Why the app doesn't just crash ? No idea !!!

---

I also needed to set *appName* string in "values" folder and not in "values-sv" as it's not a translatable string. If you don't do that, the app will not crash but your app name will be your package name ;)

C.